# Spring security role hierarchy with Wicket

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, wicket

I would like to take advantage of using role hierarchies feature from Spring Security in Apache Wicket framework. Namely to authorize access to individual web pages. Wicket is set up to get roles from security context so I can use this without any problem:

```java
@AuthorizeInstantiation({"ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_USER"})
public class HomePage extends BasePage
```

I have set up the role hierarchy so that ADMIN is higher than USER

```java
@Bean
public RoleHierarchy roleHierarchy()
{
    RoleHierarchyImpl roleHierarchy = new RoleHierarchyImpl();
    roleHierarchy.setHierarchy("ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_USER");
    return roleHierarchy;
}
```

and it works fine when I access authorized endpoint */hello* with ADMIN role only:

```java
http.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/hello").hasRole("USER")
```

Ideally, I would like to do something like this:

```java
// Caution: invalid code - for demonstration only
@AuthorizeInstantiation("hasRole('USER')")
public class HomePage extends BasePage
```

Sub-question:
If it is not possible on class level, what is the clean way to prevent Wicket to render a component, e.g. BookmarkablePageLink, on the basis of role hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with Spring Security role hierarchies but I have the feeling the following just work:

```
@AuthorizeInstantiation({"ROLE_USER"})
public class HomePage extends BasePage
```

I.e. it will allow the instantiation of the page is the current user is in role `USER` or higher, i.e. `ADMIN` should be OK too.

wicket-auth-roles project does not support Spring specifics like `hasRole()` and similar.

About your second question: You could override `Component#isEnabled()` (or even better `Component#onConfigure()` + a call to `Component#setEnabled(boolean)`. You can use Spring Security APIs to calculate the value of `enabled` boolean.

Comment: I've double-checked and must inform you that you're not correct. As you know, @AuthorizeInstantiation is a Wicket annotation that accepts parameters from Wicket roles. With Marc Giffing's wicket-spring-boot, roles are loaded automatically from the Spring Security context, allowing Wicket to know all the roles. However, it's unclear how Wicket would reflect the role hierarchy. Even Spring Security itself needs to call 'hasRole' or a similar method in the security chain. Thank you for your expert assistance!